# Trouble installing Arch on an i686 Samsung Chromebook

Tags: bios, chrome-book, chrome-os

Tryong to boot an Arch liveUSB. Can't install SeaBios, but I was able to enable developer mode. Legacy boot is obviously not working right now.

My Chromebook: https://flash.newegg.com/product/N82E16834132174

Let's just hope I didn't waste a hundred dollars.

Comment: Archlinux does not support 32 bits anymore.

Comment: See https://archlinux32.org/